# Docker container can't execute java that is install

Tags: docker, unix, centos

On my container, I share a volume containing java. But when I try to use it on my container, bash say that java is not found... do you know why ?

```
[root@mymachine~]# docker exec -ti agent1 /bin/bash
6a8618f52c72:/home/jenkins# /opt/software/java/jdk-11/bin/java -version
bash: /opt/software/java/jdk-11/bin/java: cannot execute: required file not found
6a8618f52c72:/home/jenkins# ls -al /opt/software/java/jdk-11/bin/
total 512
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root          4096 Apr  2 13:05 .
drwxrwxrwx    8 root     root            96 Apr  2 13:05 ..
-rwxr-xr-x    1 668      668          12952 Aug 23  2018 jaotc
-rwxr-xr-x    1 668      668           8736 Aug 23  2018 jar
-rwxr-xr-x    1 668      668           8736 Aug 23  2018 jarsigner
-rwxr-xr-x    1 668      668           8672 Aug 23  2018 java
-rwxr-xr-x    1 668      668           8784 Aug 23  2018 javac
```

Comment: how did you install jdk-11 on your local using rpm or yum or tar.gz ?According to experience, I prefer that using the tar.gz package to install jdk-11 and mount the dir into container using **volume.**

Comment: `ls -al /opt/software/java/jdk-11/bin/` And there is no `java` file. `I share a volume containing java` ?? Why would you do that? How do you know that it is compatible with the container?

Comment: Sorry @KamilCuk Copy/paste was wrong. I updated my post

Comment: @lemoana, Neither. Java targ.gz is a nexus package that has already be install on other centos host and is OK. Just untar it on the directory. 

On the docker host running the container, command is OK :

[root@mymachine~]# /opt/software/java/jdk-11/bin/java -version
openjdk version "11" 2018-09-25
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11+28)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11+28, mixed mode)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make sure it contains a [mcve].  Are you `RUN tar xzf ...` the tar file in a Dockerfile, or does it get into the container to some other way?  To reiterate @KamilCuk's question, are you sure that JRE is compatible with the runtime environment in the container?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks

Effectively container Jenkins/ss-agent have another jdk on it and this one was use instead my own mount jdk.